# Nodejs Mysql lib error "Too many connections"

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, connection-pooling, mysqljs

Libary that I use: mysqljs/mysql

I have 250 max connections limit on mysql server, but my application sometimes get "Too many connections".

When I checked, mysql server only have 3 connections using `show full processlist;` command

Am I doing something wrong in my code?

app/config/database.json

```
{
    "production": {
        "db1": {
            "multipleStatements": true,
            "host": ****,
            "user": ****,
            "password": ****,
            "database": ****,
            "connectionLimit": 190,
            "port": 3306
        }
}
```

app/models/index.js

```
const mysql = require('mysql')
const config = require('../config/database')

const db1 = mysql.createPool(config[process.env.APP_ENV].db1)
const db2 = mysql.createPool(config[process.env.APP_ENV].db2)
const db3 = mysql.createPool(config[process.env.APP_ENV].db3)
const db4 = mysql.createPool(config[process.env.APP_ENV].db4)

const connections = {
    'db1': db1,
    'db2': db2,
    'db3': db3,
    'db4': db4
}

// Models
const News = require('./News')
const Programs = require('./Programs')

module.exports = {
    News: new News(connections),
    Programs: new Programs(connections)
}
```

app/models/News.js

```
class News {
    constructor(connections) {
        this.db = connections;
    }

    getNews(limit, offset) {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            this.db.db1.getConnection((err, db1) => {
                if (err) {
                    console.log(err)
                    db1.destroy()
                    reject(err)
                }

                db1.query(query, (err, rows) => {
                    if (err) {
                        console.log(err)
                        db1.destroy()
                        reject(err)
                    }
                    db1.destroy()
                    resolve(rows)
                });
            });
        }); 
    }
}
module.exports = News;
```

app/controllers/NewsController.js

```
const models = require('../models/index')

class NewsController {

    index (req, res) {
        models.News.getNews(limit, offset).then((result) => {
            res.status(200).send(result);
        }).catch((err) => {
            res.status(503).send(err);
        });
    }

    // more functions that can perform 2 or 3 queries consecutives 
    // with differents model functions.
}
module.exports = NewsController
```

app/controllers/index.js

```
const NewsController = require('./NewsController')

module.exports = {
    NewsController: new NewsController()
    // more controllers...
}
```

app/routes.js

```
const express = require('express')
const router = express.Router()
const controllers = require('./controllers')

router.get('/news', (req, res) => {
    controllers.NewsController.index(req, res)
})
// more routes with newscontroller...
```

Comment: Check `SHOW GLOBAL STATUS LIKE 'max_used_connections';` in mysql client. This will tell you the high-water level of number of connections (since the last time mysqld restarted). It's possible you hit the max connections limit briefly, and then it drops back down.

Comment: @BillKarwin 171

Answer (score 0):

[The documentation](https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql#pooling-connections) states:

> `pool.getConnection` → `connection.query` → `connection.release`

You're not calling `release` but `destroy`, which immediately *terminates* the connection, instead of releasing it back to the pool. So your pools fill up with new connections.

Also, given how you only use the pooled connection to run a single query, you can use the shortcut also mentioned in the documentation:

```
this.db.db1.query(query, (err, rows) => {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err)
    reject(err)
  } else {
    resolve(rows)
  }
});
```

That way, all the pool management is being done automatically.

Comment: "If you would like to close the connection and remove it from the pool, use connection.destroy() instead. The pool will create a new connection the next time one is needed." - Documentation. 

I think there is no problem using destroy instead release, because it will create a new connection when it is needed. I don't use release because it keeps connections idle and new users can face "too many connections". I already tested this...

Comment: What's the use of a connection pool (which, in the case of `mysql`, is lazy) if you're destroying each connection that it provides? It means that for each query a new connection is created, so you might as well not use a pool at all. Also, I think that `connectionLimit` in that situation doesn't do what you think it does, namely rate-limiting the number of connections that get created. And lastly: are `db1-4` hosted on different MySQL server instances, or are they 4 databases on the same server. Not sure if MySQL connection limits are per-database or per-server (I think the latter, though).

Comment: All databases are on another server. You are right about everything that you said, but I don't see what can cause too many connections problem...

In documentation says "connectionLimit: The maximum number of connections to create at once. (Default: 10)"

If I undestand well, if I use 1 connection this number will decrease 1, but when I close it (destroy), this number keeps on 10, not 9.

Comment: The "at once" in that sentence is vague. It doesn't explicitly say that it will create _at most_ 10 connections, so I'm not sure what it actually does when you take a connection from the pool and subsequently destroy it. My sense is that it will not limit the amount of total connections to `connectionLimit` that way, in which case the # of connections may grow if the query takes a bit of time and the requests keep coming in.

Comment: Yeah, I will change to not use pool and see if this will stop too many connections error.

Comment: It's beginning to sound like the server limit is less than 250. Try using a pool as intended (`getConnection`, `query`, `release`), but with a much lower `connectionLimit`. I assume that you can't actually raise the # of connections in the MySQL-server?